# Xcode - typedef with enum - Expected '}'

Tags: ios, c, xcode, enums, typedef

I am working on Xcode 5.1.1 and I have got an error in a C-file that is supposed to work perfectly.

```
typedef enum {NO = 0, YES = 1} EnBool;
```

> ```
> ! Expected '}'
> ```

The debugger focuses on the first brace, it is like it does not want it whereas there is an enumeration just behind.

Comment: that does not suppose to work perfectly, regarding the `NO` and `YES` are already defined macros... you have to choose different names, like `myNO` or `myYES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NO` and `YES` are keywords (Actually macros) in `Objective C`, you can't use them as enum labels.

It is defined in `objc.h` and it's implementation looks like:

---

[image: Bool]

---

Use any other labels like:

```
typedef enum {nothing = 0, something = 1} EnBool;
```

Comment: Note that they are Objective-C keywords, not C keywords (and the question is tagged as C), but your answer is still valid and it's a good idea not to use NO or YES in iOS code.

Comment: @PaulR: Yes, you are correct. I just modified my answer :)

Comment: @PaulR, for being correct, they are macros only not keywords, like `#define NO  __objc_no` or `#define NO  ((BOOL)0)`.

Comment: @holex: yes, sloppy use of terminology by me - they are indeed macros.